# How to solve this dependency installation erros?

Tags: react-native, npm

Facing these console errors while installing dependencies please guide if someone faced the same error

I tried with --force but that's not working & skipping most of dependencies

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mstore-multivendor@1.2.2
npm ERR! Found: react@16.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=15.2.0" from react-native-image-view@2.1.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-image-view
npm ERR!     react-native-image-view@"^2.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.3.1" from react-native@0.55.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.44.0" from react-native-image-view@2.1.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-image-view
npm ERR!     react-native-image-view@"^2.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ASHIR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Have you tried with `--legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch of react version of in the same project. Search with the react: 15.2... and try to replace the version with same version, delete node_modules and try doing npm install or yarn in your project folder.